# How to Restart Program at End of Code in C# Console?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a exercise where you develop a console app that you enter a speed limit and speed and then it tells you if over, how much, and how many demerit points per every 5kmh over. (12 demerit point is license suspended)

I am wondering how I would restart the code back to the beginning to calculate another speed?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the speed limit:  ");
    var speedLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter the car speed:  ");
    var carSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    const int demeritPoint = 5;
    var pointTotal = (carSpeed - speedLimit) / demeritPoint;
    if (speedLimit >= carSpeed)
        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
    else if (speedLimit < carSpeed && pointTotal < 12)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Speed is" + " " + (carSpeed - speedLimit) + "kmh " + "Over");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(pointTotal + " " + "Deremit Points");
    }
    else if (speedLimit < carSpeed && pointTotal >= 12)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Speed is" + " " + (carSpeed - speedLimit) + "kmh " + "Over");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(pointTotal + " " + "Deremit Points");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("SUSPENDED");
    }
    Console.Write("Press enter to clear:");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You can wrap the body of your main do-while loop and instruct the user to hit a certain key to restart. If the entered value matches, the while loop will restart.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445836/how-can-i-make-the-same-code-repeat-until-the-player-answers-differently may be worth a read.

Comment: Put the code into a Loop. Personally I like a do...while loop for consoles. It is not much use elswehre, but ideal for console.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart your application for this, running your code into loop will solve your problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  while(true) {
    // Complete piece of code
  }
}
```

Instead of using **true** in the condition, you can add terminating condition for your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
string rerun="n" ;
do
  {
//your code
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? y / n ");
rerun = Console.ReadLine();
 }
while (rerun == "y");
```